# Formula not using else percentage value (CRYSTALREPORT)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Hello I'm a beginner to this stuff still. my formula is to help show a percentage of a part with a tariff. ex: partcost+Tariff%.

I'm trying to make it say 0 instead of a 1.10 from the test I'm running

heres formula:

```
if ({tblItem.ItemType} <> 2)
  then({@dspRecExt}) + (1+({tblHarmonizationCodes.Percentage}/100))
   else 0;
```

Unless It's a simple mistake and looked up wrong I don't know why this doesnt turn a "1.10" into "0"

Comment: Have you tried adding `{tblItem.ItemType}` to your report as a field so you can be 100% positive that it's value is 2?  For the way your IF THEN ELSE statement is written, the ELSE should only execute when ItemType is exactly 2.

Comment: The item type for some reason is the only way to pull the data from database. If i remove it the column will go away. VS2005 and 2008 crashes. But I'll try to mess with the values with the itemtype to see if that works

Comment: What type of `vba` is this?

Comment: My bad I edited to vb.net